# "desert island" versus "deserted island"

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, collocation

What is the difference between "a desert island" and "a deserted island"? Are they synonymous?

Comment: I would definitely say that the action implied in the participle 'deserted' is important here.

Comment: @Rathony: is this protection or protection racket? Find the goose that lays golden eggs and then move in for the kill?

Comment: How come a question which was a fine question for a whole year all of a sudden has become inadequate? It is the suddenness that surprises me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think people are being misled by overly literal interpretations. Let's first note this definition from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/desert-island) (it's also the one automatically shown by Googling [define desert island](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=define%20desert%20island&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=))...

> **desert island** *- a remote **tropical** island, **typically** an uninhabited one*
>   "Carwyn seemed like a castaway on a desert island"

I would say that word "typically" is crucial, in that it implies a *desert island* might not in fact be uninhabited. Particularly since the usage example implies at least one inhabitant (the castaway lives there, even if he hopes his residence will be temporary).

More importantly, I can find [any](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/desert-island) [number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_island) [of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/desert+island) [online](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/desert+island) [definitions](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/desert-island) for *desert island* (that's 5 just there). To all intents and purposes, *no* dictionaries explicitly define *deserted island* - if you want to know what that means, you have to look up each word separately and work it out yourself.

Actually, that's not strictly true. If you search for [define "deserted island"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=define%20desert%20island&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=#hl=en&q=define%20%22deserted%20island%22) Google appears to show a definition for those exact words, but in fact it's just redirecting to the *desert island* definition. Wkipedia does something similar, in that the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deserted_island goes to the same page as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_island.

---

I hope that's enough to show ***desert island*** is a well-known collocation with numerous specific connotations to most Anglophones (notably including [Robinson Crusoe](http://www.classicreader.com/book/48/3/), [Desert Island Discs](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/features/desert-island-discs), and [humorous postcards](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=desert%20island%20jokes%20postcards%20pictures&rlz=1C2CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=62bJUqnaFePd7QbdgYGIDw&ved=0CEQQsAQ&biw=1205&bih=813)). Whereas ***deserted island*** is just two words that might occur consecutively.

In short, whether there's any etymological justification for it or not, most Anglophones understand ***desert island*** as *tropical, sandy-beached, [probably] without permanent inhabitants,* etc., etc. They certainly wouldn't use that collocation in respect of [uninhabited islands of Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aUninhabited_islands_of_Scotland), for example (which they might well be prepared to call ***deserted islands***).

---

TL;DR: ***desert*** island evokes *arid, sandy, desert-like*,  ***deserted*** evokes *uninhabited, abandoned*.
Dictionaries can only take you so far. In this case, established *cultural* associations are crucial.

Comment: Could one say, then, that 'deserted island' is just a collocation, whereas 'desert island' is a collocation which has evolved into a noun phrase, a compound noun?

Comment: @user58319: Pretty much, yes. I only posted my answer because I thought it was hopelessly misleading of the existing answer to say they're ***often** used as if they were synonyms*. The reality is that *as a pair of words, "**desert island**"* has two or three well-known and closely-connected meanings that are only distantly related to the [far less common "alternative"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deserted+island%2Cdesert+island&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeserted%20island%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesert%20island%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...you probably can't see it, because it you need high rep to see deleted answers, but another user posted and then deleted an answer including the text *It comes from 'desert' in the sense of sandy expanse of nothingness. So a **desert island** is a sandy island with nothing (or very little) alive.*. He probably only deleted it because he was intimidated by people throwing weighty dictionaries in his direction. But if he *hadn't*, I'd have just upvoted [@Rory Alsop's](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3820/rory-alsop) answer and left it at that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, or maybe he deleted it because he realised it’s not etymologically correct. _Desert_ (the noun) originally just meant ‘abandoned/deserted/desolate, remote, wilderness of a place’; it is etymologically related to the verb ‘to desert’. Up until the 19th century, _desert_ was also used of places that are not arid or sandy, and a _desert island_ was originally just a simple collocation of the two words. Only when _desert_ became narrowed down to a specifically dry, sandy, arid area did _desert island_ really become a compound with a non-transparent meaning.

Comment: @Janus: I'm not too sure about your *non-transparent meaning* there. I'm not really interested in the etymology as such here, but it seems obvious to me that most people *today* would strongly associate ***desert** island* with *sandy, arid* - the *uninhabited* connotations arise almost incidentally from that. I'm astonished that the overwhelmingly-favoured answer here (75% of which is irrelevant digression) makes no mention of this association, and simply defines the "standard" form as an island which has *never* been inhabited (as opposed to one which has been inhabited and then abandoned).

Answer (score 11):

They are often used as if they were synonymous… But, "a desert island" is "an island which has never been inhabited, which is and has always been uninhabited", whereas "a deserted island" **should** mean "an island which once was inhabited but whose inhabitants left for one reason or another, whose inhabitants **deserted** it".

Although I am sure that this **should**, this normative attitude towards languages, is definitely not everybody's cup of tea!

This reminds me of a game show I once saw on (French) TV: the people on set were given a phrase like 'not to beat about the bush' and given four different meanings the phrase might have.

The presenters had asked a hundred people in the street to choose between the different meanings. To win the game, the people on set did not have to give the correct meaning of the phrase, but the meaning which had been chosen by most people.

At first this sounded preposterous to me… but then it dawned on me that this is exactly the way languages work in the long run: a mistake made by a majority of people ends up not being one!

An example: in French, the morello cherry — a variety of very dark sour cherry — is *l'agriotte* from *aigre*, meaning 'sour' ('eager' belongs to the same word family as *aigre*). A lot of people misdivided this and ended up with *la griotte*… which is the correct form today! This is parallel to Shakespeare's humorous *nuncle* used by the Fool to address King Lear, a misdivision of *an uncle*, like so many innocent ones coming from the mouths of children.

[etymology of the French word 'griotte' on Wikipedia](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/griotte)

[etymology of the English adjective 'eager' on Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=eager)

[origin of the word 'nuncle', Merriam-Webster Dictionary and Thesaurus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuncle)

Similarly, when enough people have used Huckleberry Finn's *nonnamous* instead of *anonymous*, when Greek is Greek to enough of us, and when humorous or mistaken has become plain, *nonnamous* might become correct!

Comment: I like your answer, but it would be better with links. ;)

Comment: @Susan I had a look at the definitions of the noun phrase 'desert island' and the adjective 'deserted' in the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English. I am currently discussing 'Lord of the Flies' with my students and repeatedly heard 'deserted island' instead of 'desert island', which made me wonder whether they were synonyms or not.

Comment: Very interesting, and an excellent example.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of [rebracketing](http://www.odlt.org/ballast/rebracketing.html) to be found in English. [Apron](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=apron&searchmode=none) is the one that comes to my mind straight away but more in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing#In_English).

Comment: So if I am stranded on a *desert island*, it is no longer a *desert island* since it is now inhabited. And when I am rescued it will then become a *deserted island*, never again to be a *desert island*?

Comment: In 'Lord of The Flies' still, you find the following sentence, right after Ralph, Roger and Jack flee the mountain top because they have seen 'the beast': "Ralph found himself taking giant strides among the ashes, heard other creatures crying out and leaping and dared the impossible on the dark slope; presently the mountain was deserted, save for the three abandoned sticks and the thing that bowed." Where clearly 'desert' would not work.

Comment: my answer is only partly in defence of usage. To me, 'in the long run' is a very important caveat: if there isn't a modicum of agreement, then no communication is possible; right and wrong have to hold for a while.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is one of those phrases which has gotten misused with time. Deserted island became desert island because people left off the "ed". There us no basis of comparison for an island with a desert because the word desert has an explicit meaning which is unrelated to an island unless the topography is like that of a desert and the fact that it is surrounded by water dismisses some if that slight similarity even.

Comment: To a British-English speaker, like me, the point of a "desert island" is that it has the characteristics of a desert as well as an island.  The stereotypical desert island is hot, sandy and has coconut palms growing on it.

Answer (score -2):

Deserted implies uninhabited, not necessarily once, but no longer, inhabited. Desert, as in "desert island," is an otherwise obsolete form of deserted. Compare "For oh, for oh, the hobby horse is forgot," (instead of "forgotten.")

Comment: That use of _forgot_ is completely different from _desert_. _Forgot_ is just an alternative past participle of _forget_, while _desert_ /ˈdɛzəɹt/ is synchronically quite unrelated to _desert_ /dɪˈzəɹt/.

Comment: Desert: deserted, forsaken (archaic). The source is the Merriam Webster New International Dictionary, 2nd Ed.

Comment: Desert: deserted, forsaken (archaic). The source is the Merriam Webster New International Dictionary, 2nd Ed.  "Desert" is an archaic past participle, as is "forgot."

Comment: That doesn’t mean it’s an obsolete **form** of _deserted_, just that it’s an archaic adjective with the same meaning. _Deserted_ is the past participle of the verb; _desert_ is not, it is just an adjective. [After your edit:] The online version of Merriam Webster (which is all I have access to) has no mention of it as a participle, and while the OED claims that it was “sometimes” used as one, it has no citations to back it up.